# Listview run behind textview

Tags: android, listview, textview

I need to make a listview run behind a textview on Android but I don't know how to do it. It means that the textview location is fixed, my responsibility is to scroll the listview which run behind the textview. I appreciate any help from you. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work

```
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:text="Sample" android:layout_alignParentTop="True"/>
    <ListView android:layout_width=="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

You can use any other parameters you want to align textview where you like on the screen.

Edit: Corrected the order, TextView need to be added first and then ListView in order for TextView to stay on top

Comment: Thank you very much. I tried your solution and found it really cool. However, the thing I want is to make the textview on top of the listview, not just only on top of the background. It means that when we scroll the listview, a part of it will stay behind the textview. Thank you.

Comment: I think this solution works the way you want it to. I think all I did wrong was the order of these two. Let me edit it and you can try it out.